Making polygons that don't overlap based around smaller polygons that don't touch
I want to divide an area into spaces that are similar in population and area. The map I'm making is supposed to show where a sweeper truck has and hasn't been going. I turned the routes the truck goes from lines to points so polygons can count the points within and I can base symbology upon that. I have a shp of census blocks that includes the population in each block. I also have a shp of neighborhoods as polygons. However, the neighborhood polygons don't touch and leave lots of space between each other.
How can I make polygons around each neighborhood that are roughly equal in population and don't leave space between each other?

Suggest you add images to your question to show what you want.

Does the 'Build Balanced Zones' tool do what you require?  It has a lot of different options.  See:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/buildbalancedzones.htm
